# Pictures are missing in Internal memory in Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: internal-storage, images, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

*Tab Model - Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 GT-P3100, Android version - 4.1.1*

Files in the DCIM folder both Pictures & Videos are missing in the internal memory.
I'm sure that I haven't deleted them. I tried below options, but no positive results:

1. Tried connected to my Windows 7 PC, but its detected as Portable Media Device (as MTP mode) and not able to trace the files with the file recovery software as they detect only logical drives.
2. Tried with Wondershare Android data recovery software (Trial Pack), but still I didn't find even a single deleted Picture/Video file in it.
3. In order to convert to USB mass storage mode (this option is missing in android 4.1.1 by default), as recommended in few sites, I've rooted my tab, downloaded the terminal app and changed the config file but no use. Windows 7 failed to detect the tab as USB mass storage device.

I don't want to lose my pictures & videos. How can I retrieve my files?

Comment: The folder is just completely absent?

Comment: You haven't deleted them but someone may have deleted them. Files won't disappear by themselves. May I ask you a question? Is the Rooting successful?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would like to ask you one more thing, I don't think the files images and videos created inside the DICM folder at least I can't see it over my device and yes it's also GT-P3100 but running 4.2.2. I would say if you are trying to recover things then why don't you try recovering your data using "Recuva" I have tried using it a number of times to recover some of my images. So, it does seems okay try giving it a shot if you're luck is good enough then I am sure you can get at least some of your images back.

Comment: But "Recuva" looks for a drive.....android 4.1.1 doesn't show/recognize it as a drive. "Recuva" provides any recovery for internal memory of android tablets especially for 4.1.1.

Comment: Well, I actually can't comment over it because haven't test Recuva over the 4.1.1 Jellybean I have tried it over Jellybean 4.2.2 over my tab. :( Couldn't help !